# Div hover functionality is not behaving as expected

Tags: css

I am trying to create a drop-down when I hover over an image.  It works but it moves my images around.  Here's what it looks like initially with just one image having the hover over functionality.

[image]

Here's the code

```
  <table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td width=10%>
  <div><a href=""><img height="300" width="300" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" /></a></div>
     </td>
      <td>
      <div class="image1 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
    <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="image2 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="image3"><img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="image4"><img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" /></div>

  <div class="image1"><img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" /></div>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

When I add additional dropdowns to the other images, it gives me the image below.  I think part of the reason is because I have it formatted with an html table.
Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

For more details, here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/GRJeyeX?editors=1100)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's jump right to an alternative fix:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-1,
.row-5 {
  margin-left: 190px
}

.row-2,
.row-4 {
  margin-left: 150px
}

.row-3 {
  margin-left: 130px
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column" <a href=""><img height="300" width="300" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="img-rows row-1 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-rows row-2 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-rows row-3 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-rows row-4 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-rows row-5 dropdown">
      <img height="80" width="80" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dfrZsdS7L._AC_SY400_.jpg" />
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First, not related to why things are failing, using tables for layout is no longer the "modern" way of the web (this is an opinion, not a law!). My example uses a flex box method, so you can hopefully gleam something from the example.

Now, as to why your example is failing...

You have a class, called "dropdown", this class has the display set at "inline-block". All you have to do to fix your code is change it to "block".

From https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_inline-block.asp:

> Compared to display: block, the major difference is that display:
>   inline-block does not add a line-break after the element, so the
>   element can sit next to other elements.

Change the class to this:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Then everything should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you!  I do need to get better at flexbox